# Minecraft PE(json) command

Tags: json, minecraft, minecraft-commands

Why is this command not working? How can I fix it? I watched all the videos and none of them could explain.

`/give @p gold_ingot 1 0 {"display":[{Name:"help"}]}`

Comment: Minecraft Java Edition is a different game than Minecraft Pocket Edition. Why do you expect them to use the same commands?

Answer (score 0):

It was updated and it is now `/give @p gold_ingot{"display":[{Name:"texthere"}]}`